# Can a Dragon Mage wear magic armour?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

In the 8th Edition High Elf book the Dragonmage is equipped with heavy armour. This is very unusual for a (non-chaos) wizard. A *normal* wizard cannot wear armour, magic or otherwise.

Does the fact that can wear normal armour mean he can be upgraded with magic Armour/Shields/Helms or is he forced to keep standard armour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

In 8th edition the **"Magical Interference"** rule (Magic Items, pg 500) says:

> Wizards cannot choose magic armour unless they have an option for
>   'normal' armour.

It goes on to say that most Wizards cannot use magic while wearing armour, but that any Wizard that *"has armour as part of his standard equipment or an option for 'normal' armour"* is an exception, having trained to do so without penalty.

As such, any wizard with armour/access to armour can wear it and cast spells as normal, and can be upgraded with magical armour.

However, most wizards do not have access to armour.